# Problem with declaring a protected pointer to a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, compiler-errors

I'm trying to declare a pointer to a `std::vector<int>` in a derived class in C++. That class is a base class for other classes again.

My attempt was as follows

```
protected:
   std::vector<CustomClass> *mypointer;
```

However, when I compile it, I get the following error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘std::vector<int>*’)
error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::vector<int>’)
```

and some other operands are missing.

I'm pretty clueless, where the problem lies at all. Do I have to implement all those functions in the current class? If so, why do I have to do so?

For anyone needing more context, I want to implement that pointer in the class CbmStsSensor [(found here)](https://lxcbmredmine01.gsi.de/projects/cbmroot/repository/show/trunk/sts/setup), which derives from CbmStsElement.

Edit: Some relevant classes can be found here [CbmStsElement.h](https://pastebin.com/s9S5LvPh) and here [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/vTpRV9wk).

Edit2: The whole compilation error log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/QY4m4KsS).

Comment: Firefox warned me that that website is a potential security risk. Submit all relevant code in the question, not as links to external sites.

Comment: The snippet you showed isn't sufficient to diagnose the problem.  The error message sounds like you're trying to assign a non-pointer to `mypointer` though.

Comment: @John added two relevant files.

Comment: @StephenNewell the problem is, I'm not even trying to assign anything. Just by declaring that pointer, the compilation error already occurs with the given messages.

Comment: This is still far from a [mre].

Comment: The problem is, I can't give a minimal example, because every example I tried to create, it worked. I think it has something to do with some operators being overwritten in the base class. But I can't corner it down to where and why. If the two given classes are not enough, I can provide more classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't the c++ code itself, but the framework it used, in this case ROOT. If you define a pointer in a ROOT class, you have to tell the program what to do with that pointer in the case of the class being written to file. Even though the class might never be written to a file (like in my case).
In this specific case (class never being written to a file), you can simply tell ROOT to ignore the given pointer by adding `//!` after the declaration, e.g. write

```
protected:
   std::vector<CustomClass> *mypointer; //!
```

Thanks to everyone for helping in this helpless case!

Answer (score 0):

The error messages are enough clear. For example somewhere in the code you are trying to assign a pointer to an object of the type `std::vector<int> *` to an object of the type `std::vector<int>`.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how this error message can be generated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1;
    std::vector<int> v2;

    v1 = &v2;

    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error is

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:9:8: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::vector<int>’ and ‘std::vector<int>*’)
  v1 = &v2;
        ^~
```

Or (relative to the second error message) there is no unary `operator *` for objects of the type `std::vector<int>`.

Here is another demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    *v;

    return 0;
}
```

the error message is

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:8:2: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘std::vector<int>’)
  *v;
  ^~
```

Maybe you should declare the data member as having the type `std::vector<int>` instead of the pointer type.

Comment: It shouldn't be the first, because just by declaring that pointer I'm already getting the compilation error messages. Can you explain the latter?

Comment: @Rhynden I have not understood what you mean.

Comment: Just by declaring the pointer, I already get the compilation error, so I don't understand why I get the error `for operator=`. 
Shouldn't there be the operator  * for a simple std::vector<int>?

Comment: @Rhynden The compiler usually shows the code that was the reason of an error.

Comment: Sadly, I can't declare it as a simple vector, because other classes derive from that class, but they all have to share the same vector and additionally, that vector is passed from another class. I added the whole compilation log, if you'd like to take a look at it.